# How to prevent to access visited page after logout in laravel using middleware class?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to make prevent access to visited page after logout from the laravel project. Here I have used laravel middleware

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function ()
 {
        Route::get('/logout',[
           'uses'=>'UserController@getLogout',
             'as'=>'logout'  
        ]);
 });
```

I have included the all the routes in above  **Route::group** route
and used **auth** facade. I want to prevent to access visited page after logout and after accidentally pressing the back button from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel Route middleware can be used to allow only authenticated users to access a given route. All you need to do is attach the middleware to a route definition:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);
```

Check this [Laravel Auth Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

Comment: Thank you . The link you provided is very informative!